# return UIViewController from a class function

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller

In my `Restaurant` model I have a function, that returns `UINavigationController`, I've implemented it to make my code more readable. But I am curious if it is ok to do it this way, or should I make a function of `UIViewController`, that takes `Restaurant` as a parameter.

```
func reserveTable(timeIndex: Int) -> UINavigationController {
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Reservations", bundle: nil)
    let targetVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "bookingNC") as! UINavigationController
    let destinationVC = targetVC.topViewController as! BookingViewController
    destinationVC.availabeleDates = self.schedule
    destinationVC.timeRange = self.avaliableTimes
    destinationVC.restaurantId = self.id
    destinationVC.requestedTimeIndex = timeIndex
    destinationVC.reservationType = "Бронирование"
    return targetVC
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this differently, your model is supposed to handle data, not Views.

There are many ways in which you could do this, personally I would have a property on the booking controller for the reservation. Then you could just do something like:

```
let vc = BookingViewController()
vc.reservation = reservation
self.present(vc, animated: true)
```

wherever you needed to present the booking controller. Ensuring you have a reservation first.

In your init/viewDidLoad method of the BookingViewController you can do alot of the work above...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let reservation = self.reservation {
        self.availabeleDates = reservation.schedule
        self.timeRange = reservation.avaliableTimes
        self.restaurantId = reservation.id
        self.requestedTimeIndex = timeIndex
        self.reservationType = "Бронирование"
    }  
}
```

Comment: I used to have similar code, but it actually makes my code a bit messy, because my `ReservationViewController` might have `Reservation` class instance, if user is in an edit mode, and might not, if user creates new one. So I had a few `if-else` blocks. In this case, should I pass whole `Restaurant` instance and parse data in `ReservationViewController`? I thought that passing a lot of extra data is bad practice. Thank you.

Comment: for cleaner code seperation you could look at using an MVVM approach. Theres loads of great articles on the web for this. The main point here is that the models purpose is for data only, it should not be configuring views, if the view is based off some data, it should take this data and configure itself. a viewmodel can also help with this to split the code out a bit